# Best way to present alternate view to user

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

In my Apple Watch app, I need to have a way to be able to notify the user that they must first set something from within the iPhone version of my app before they can use the Watch App. Obviously, I need to do to this through a few labels and images, however the layout of these is different to the layout of the main views in my app.

How can I present the user with a different view based on the status of the iPhone app, that they cannot see unless required? The way I would do something similar in a normal app would be to just push to a different view controller, but obviously this is not possible in a watch app.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always present a modal interface controller. Alternatively, you could create a separate group in your root controller's view and show/hide that as necessary.

To check the status of the iPhone app, the easiest solution would likely be to use a shared NSUserDefaults suite between the iPhone app and the Watch app. Set a value to true/YES when your criteria has been met and check that value in the Watch app.